# Magento 2.1.2 Content > Pages Loading Loop

Tags: admin, magento-2.1, backend, admin-panel, cms-pages

I have a problem with my Magento 2 backend only with the pages section. 
It just is stuck in a Loading loop (see screenshot)
I have been looking and asking all over the net and forums without anyone replying to my issue. Hopefully i have more success here. :)
[image] 
I do not get any error logs only when I switch to Console in Chrome it gives me the following:[image: Console error]

Im still pretty new to magento and not exactly sure what causes the problem or how to fix it. Any ideas guys.

Comment: Probably you have not handled special characters when json was created.Just view how your json object looks like.

Comment: @oscprofessionals thank you for your answer. It was all working fine and then it just happened I only changed to a different page layout.

How can I fix this problem any tips?

Comment: error states unexpected token < in json so you need to look at json thats created.  Here is some discussion on issue you are facing https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1643